# Condense list by a particular column for use with mail merge

Tags: excel, email, merge, aggregate

I have a particularly involved problem I'm looking to tackle, but I'll try and keep it concise:

End goal: use Mail Merge to create a giant stack of letters customized to each particular recipient.

Data set I was given:

```
Company    e-mail                   Part Num    Part Descr.
broncos    jman@hotmail.com         6S          iphone 6s plus
broncos    pey_me@nationwide.com    5S          iphone 5s
saints     drew@NOLA.gov            6           iphone 6
broncos    jman@hotmail.com         6S+         iphone 6s plus
packers    A-A-ron@pac.com          6           iphone 6
falcons    MattyIce@yahoo.com       5C          iphone 5C
saints     drew@NOLA.gov            6+          iphone 6 plus
dolphins   rhill@gmail.net          5S          iphone 5S
jets       Tebow@uf.edu             5           iphone 5
jets       Tebow@uf.edu             5           iphone 5
```

Now, the tricky part is I'd like to create a letter (Again, via mail merge) on a per e-mail address basis...so *I THINK* what I need to change this data set in to is:

```
Company    e-mail                   Part Num 1  Part Descr. 1    Part Num 2 Part Descr. 2
broncos    jman@hotmail.com         6S          iphone 6s plus   6S+        iphone 6s plus
broncos    pey_me@nationwide.com    5S          iphone 5s
saints     drew@NOLA.gov            6           iphone 6         6+         iphone 6 plus
packers    A-A-ron@pac.com          6           iphone 6
falcons    MattyIce@yahoo.com       5C          iphone 5C
dolphins   rhill@gmail.net          5S          iphone 5S
jets       Tebow@uf.edu             5           iphone 5
```

The problems I keep running in to when considering solutions are:

1. Number of unique Part Nums per e-mail is not constant
2. I don't want to have repeats (as in the last line item in the above example)

Now that I've written it out it seems like a simple enough problem, but for the life of me I can't think of a viable solution.  Should I be looking in to scripting (not something I've worked with yet)?

Once I figure this part out I'll be trying to learn how to use mail merge to create tables of variable length, but that's a topic for another day/post.

Many thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Where's the "Part Num 2" info. coming from? It looks like the only thing that's changing really is the addition of that column?  Also, I notice that `jets Tebow@uf.edu` is twice in your original data set, byt only once in the "final table". Do you just remove duplicates? Or should the final one with Teboe also have `5; iPhone 5` in the Part 2 num?

Comment: So really, you're just needing to scan for duplicate entries (based on Company and Email), and for any entries after the first one, add it to the row of the first one, but under "Part Num #"?

Comment: I would create a user defined object (class module) where the properties are `company`, `email` and a collection where the collection items consist of `Part number` and `Part description`.  The collect these objects into a collection with email or email/company as the key -- if you hit a duplicate object, add just the part number/description to the already added item.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - any tips on starting with Classes? I've taken a crack in the past but can't seem to get a hold of when to use it. This question looks like a good one for me to use and see what a Class is all about. (I'll of course Google around, just curious if you have any tips too).

Comment: @BruceWayne Chip Pearson's web site is an **excellent** resource.  I would start with [Introduction to Classes](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Classes.aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld -  I had a feeling his site would have something on Classes, I agree it's an excellent resource.  Thanks!!

Comment: @BruceWayne correct, that's exactly the goal - just without any pre-knowledge of how many Part Nums there are.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks! I wasn't familiar with the use of Classes (or much VBA in general, for that matter), I'll definitely take a close look at that link and see how far I can get.

Comment: Is there any chance the same email can be in two different companies?  What about the reverse, can two different companies have the same email?  (Could A-A-ron be in the Packers, *and* the Broncos with his Ba-lakay?)

Comment: @BruceWayne Those are good questions, and the answer would determine the key to be used for the Collection of UDO's.  Most likely, you could key off the email as it seems unlikely that two UDO's that don't need to be combined would have the same email address.

Comment: @user3529777 Classes are great for this kind of problem.  You should also educate yourself about Collections, and how they can be used to create unique lists. (Some people use Dictionaries for this purpose; and in certain circumstances they do have an advantage).

Comment: @BruceWayne - unfortunately, an email can be in two different companies, but that circumstance is very much so a corner case.  (So much so that, if I could automate the rest, I would be happy to manually address those as needed)

That said, the ideal result would be a line item for each unique pairing of company+email.

Comment: @JimboSlice A unique pair of email/company would be simple to do, -- merely join them to make the key for the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using Classes and Collections.
I assume the source data is on Sheet1 starting in cell A1; and the results go onto sheet2, also starting in cell A1.  (It should be readily apparent in the code where to change this).

Duplicates will be ignored.
Post back with any questions.  A collection has the feature that it returns a `457` error if you try to add an item with an already existing key.  We make use of that.

Enter the code as outlined below, in the appropriate modules.

Rename the Class Module: **`cParts`**

### Class Module

```
Option Explicit
Private pCompany As String
Private pEmail As String
Private pPartNum As String
Private pPartDesc As String
Private pParts As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pParts = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get Company() As String
    Company = pCompany
End Property
Public Property Let Company(Value As String)
    pCompany = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Email() As String
    Email = pEmail
End Property
Public Property Let Email(Value As String)
    pEmail = Value
End Property

Public Property Get PartNum() As String
    PartNum = pPartNum
End Property
Public Property Let PartNum(Value As String)
    pPartNum = Value
End Property

Public Property Get PartDesc() As String
    PartDesc = pPartDesc
End Property
Public Property Let PartDesc(Value As String)
    pPartDesc = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Parts() As Collection
    Set Parts = pParts
End Property
Public Function ADDParts(Value As Variant)
    On Error Resume Next
        pParts.Add Value, Join(Value, "|")
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineParts()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim cP As cParts, colP As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim vParts(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim lPartCols As Long
    Dim sKey As String

'Set source and results worksheets
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'Read source data into array
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=4)
End With

'collect the data
Set colP = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    Set cP = New cParts
    With cP
        .Company = vSrc(I, 1)
        .Email = vSrc(I, 2)
        .PartNum = CStr(vSrc(I, 3))
        .PartDesc = CStr(vSrc(I, 4))
            vParts(0) = .PartNum
            vParts(1) = .PartDesc
        .ADDParts (vParts)
        sKey = .Company & "|" & .Email
        colP.Add cP, sKey
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 457
                Err.Clear
                colP(sKey).ADDParts (vParts)
            Case Is <> 0
                MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description
        End Select
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'How many part columns?
For I = 1 To colP.Count
    J = colP(I).Parts.Count
    lPartCols = IIf(lPartCols > J, lPartCols, J)
Next I
lPartCols = lPartCols * 2

'Set up Results Array
ReDim vRes(0 To colP.Count, 1 To lPartCols + 2)

'Header rows
vRes(0, 1) = "Company"
vRes(0, 2) = "e-mail"
For J = 1 To lPartCols / 2
    vRes(0, (J - 1) * 2 + 3) = "Part Num " & J
    vRes(0, (J - 1) * 2 + 4) = "Part Desc. " & J
Next J

'Populate results array
For I = 1 To colP.Count
    With colP(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .Company
        vRes(I, 2) = .Email
        For J = 1 To .Parts.Count
            vRes(I, (J - 1) * 2 + 3) = .Parts(J)(0)
            vRes(I, (J - 1) * 2 + 4) = .Parts(J)(1)
        Next J
    End With
Next I

'Write to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    With .Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is awesome!

I was knee deep into a few tutorials when I saw your post, this does exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the assistance and for teaching me something new!

Comment: @JimboSlice  Hopefully there is enough documentation that, along with the tutorials, you can understand how it works, and be able to maintain it, and also adapt the approach to other tasks.  Post back if you have any questions.

Comment: Yep, definitely.  I updated it for the actual dataset (some added columns) and it seems to be working flawlessly.  If I run into further problems I'll post back - thanks again!